# Reverse proxy connection

Tags: http, proxy, connection, reverse-proxy, socks5

Salam
I need your help please.

Suppose I want to set up a socks5 proxy on my home computer so that I can forward queries from my work computer through my home computer.

So the logic would be :
Work computer connects to proxy on home, sends requests, then receives response from home proxy.

Now suppose that I can't (or I don't want to) open any port on my home router for incoming connections.

In this case, home proxy must first reverse connect to work computer then the above logic can take place.

How and what tools can I use to achieve this ?
Thanks

(I hope I was clear enough)

I don't want to use service like ngrok